# Filter out the Users logging in time

Tags: sharepoint, filter

I am new to Sharepoint 2007. I am trying to configure MOSS 2007. My question is: Can we know when a user has logged in and uploaded any document to a particular site in the central database?

I know these information can get from the logs but I want any application that give only these information in readable format. that way it will save the time to go into each log file and look for these information.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what library you're interested in, you could consider either:

- setting an alert on the library
- writing an event handler that would run your code when items are added/updated